# How to set font size, rows, and columns of ChromeOS Linux window?

Tags: google-chrome-os

Newer version of ChromeOS can open a Linux terminal window.  However I haven't been able to figure out how to easily change the number of rows and columns or the font size. There are some keyboard shortcuts, but the settings aren't saved or bookmarkable.

You can't use ESC codes to resize the windows either:

```
alias w24='printf '\''\e[8;24;80t'\'''
```

Suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> from the terminal opens the *Profile settings*.
There, under "Appearance", you will find the "Text font size" option.